# How do I make parent with nowrap inherit width of inline-blocks

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a parent to inherit the width of it's children.  The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/4mk3S/

right now I just have an outer div with

```
    white-space: nowrap;
```

and children divs with

```
    display: inline-block;
```

I would like the outer div to inherit the width of it's entire group of children.  Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Code :

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

.outer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;` to the parent also

`inline-block` forces the container to wrap all of its children while `block` (the default for div) sets the width to that of the parent

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mk3S/1/)**

Relevant code to be changed

```
.outer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
    display:inline-block;
}
```